# RAID Controller Compatibility HP ProLiant DL360 G5/6 for DL380 G5

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

I'm sorry if this question is kind of stupid, but I wonder...

Is  it possible to use the RAID Controller from a DL360 G5/G6 for a DL380 G5?

You see, we have several decommissioned DL360 G5/G6 lying around, and one DL380 G5. The DL380 we want to repurpose, but its controller does not support RAID5. I was thinking of cannibalizing the DL360s' controller to make the DL380 RAID5-capable.

Have anyone attempted something similar?

Comment: RAID Controller model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of those systems should have onboard controllers, no? The G5 models may have PCIe cards ([Smart Array P400](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12400_na/12400_na.html) is most common), but the G6 systems should have [Smart Array P410](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13201_na/13201_na.HTML) models embedded on the motherboard.

You're dealing with two generations of system, though. The G5's have different drive bay and controller connections than the G6 systems, so I would not lump the DL360 G5 and DL360 G6 together. The G5 ProLiants have [SAS SFF-8484](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SFF_8484_angled.jpg) connectors internally. The G6 ProLiant systems have [SAS SFF-8087](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SFF_8087.jpg) connectors internally.

They are vastly different systems. Can you provide the specific controller model installed in the DL380 G5, and what spare parts you have available?

Edit: I'm assuming you have a [Smart Array E200 controller](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12460_na/12460_na.html) in the DL380 G5. That controller does not support RAID 5 unless you add a Battery-Backed Cache unit (BBWC - [#351580-B21](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12460_na/12460_na.html#Related%20Options)) to the controller. Without going into the issues with deploying RAID 5, that part is all you need in order to make the DL380 G5 do what you want. If your G5 DL360 has a P400 or P800 controller available in PCIe form, you can move that over to the DL380.

Comment: Thanks for the complete explanation! Now I know what to watch for... as to the issues with RAID 5... well, I much prefer using a proper EMC/HDS/NetApp storage myself, but even if the management somehow decides to sign the P.O. today (unlikely!), I will still be looking at 2 weeks wait time... time which I unfortunately don't have ;(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, yes it is - they just work fine between them.